# Long term turtlebot storage and care

Tags: ros, battery, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have any experience with maintaining the netbook and Kobuki batteries during long term (6 months - 1 year) of storage? Do they need to be intermittently recharged?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204239/long-term-turtlebot-storage-and-care/) by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you charge the batteries and then unplug them, they should survive 6 months to a year. Open the bottom of the Kobuki and unplug the battery pack. And remove the battery from the laptop, like it was shipped.

You might want to check the batteries every couple months, and recharge them if they're low. But as long as they're unplugged they are unlikely to be damaged in that time period. I don't know that anyone has paid attention to this sort of thing so some real data would be great.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1